# How to sandbox/VM a VPN to be used by a single application?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox, vpn

I have a remote server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (headless). I want to use an enterprise VPN client (GlobalProtect) to have the server tunnel into another network for a single application, but the server already performs a number of functions that I don't want to interfere with (it would be bad if the server stopped listening on its LAN as it acts as a VPN already, among other things). As far as I know, GlobalProtect can only be configured to do split tunneling server-side, so that is unfortunately not an option.

From looking at other posts it seems the best way to accomplish this would be via a VM, though I am open to other solutions as well. How could I install vmware to host a virtual ubuntu server (headless) guest machine? And how would I then ssh into that VM (even if the VPN tunnel is active)?

It's also worth noting that I'm running UFW as my firewall. If I got the VM working, would UFW get in the way of the VM tunneled into the other network? I assume I can just configure a new instance of UFW on the VM'd OS, but if not, how could I prevent this from happening?

If it helps I already have X11 forwarding working as I can only use the GUI version of GlobalProtect because of 2FA.

All of this is based on my limited understanding of Linux and the related topics, so some of it may be inaccurate. I apologize in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have lots of services running, and don't want a complex new service to crash the entire server, then look into *containers*, which have many advantages of VMs, but use fewer resources.

Comment: A VM or a container seems like the way to go. You will need to run the Global Protect VPN client from inside the VM. Assuming you don't need a GUI that needs to run in the VM (that needs the VPN), it would be better if the Global Protect has a non-GUI client. You may want to look up QEMU-KVM for the VM. Otherwise the topic is too vast. It may be better to split it up into questions with shorter answers. Or ask questions as you run into problems.

Comment: You may also look at Canonical's [Multipass](https://snapcraft.io/multipass). It is easy to setup in any Ubuntu desktop or server.

Comment: @user68186 Multipass worked perfectly, very happy with this solution

Comment: Feel free to write an answer and describe how you did it. Then accept your answer by clicking on the grey check ✔️ and turn it green ✅.  This will help others.